# python while loop gets stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext

Why the below code gets stuck after entering either int. or str in sublime text ? same code runs fine with python3 command line or pycharm.

```py
print ('\n asks for an integer and prints the square of it\n')
def square(num):
    return num **2

def ask():
    while True:
        try:
            usr_input = int(input('Input an integer:'))
        except:
            print (f'An error occurred! Please try again!')
            continue
        else:
           return (f'Thank you, your number squared is:{square(usr_input)}')
print(ask())
```

Comment: You need to break your while True infinite loop for rhat which you are not doing now

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Surely `return` breaks the loop.

Comment: Ohh yes didn’t see that, but the OP is doing try except else which I am unsure is a valid way to use try catch. Perhaps he needs to use finally?

Comment: can you try to just execute ask() without print?

Comment: Have you ran your code through a debugger or stepped through it at all? At what point is it actually getting stuck?

Comment: It should work tho. This is probably a bad advise/comment but how long are you using sublime? Or is it needed? An alternative would be using visual studio code. That comes close to sublime.

Comment: Check what version of Python comes with your version of Sublime Text. It may trail the current version of Python, and `f`-strings were new in in Python 3.6.

Answer (score -1):

```
       return (f'Thank you, your number squared is:',square(usr_input))
print(ask())
```

You need to use square function like this.
Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

**Here is your Code**
just do one thing separate the  **square(usr_input))** and remove the curly brases

```
 print ('\n asks for an integer and prints the square of it\n')
def square(num):
    return num ** 2

def ask():
    while True:
        try:
            usr_input = int(input('Input an integer:'))
        except:
            print ('An error occurred! Please try again!')
            continue
        else:
            return ('Thank you, your number squared is:',square(usr_input))

print(ask())
```

**Output-**

```
asks for an integer and prints the square of it

Input an integer:5
('Thank you, your number squared is:', 25)
```